# The bot does not edit the embed after clicking a button. || Discord.js V.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('suggest')
        .setDescription('Make a suggestion.')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('suggestion')
                .setDescription('The suggestion you want to make.')
                .setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const suggestion = interaction.options.getString('suggestion');

        // Create the Embed message
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Suggestion')
            .setDescription(suggestion)
            .setColor("Blue");

        // Initialize the fields array
        const fields = [];
        fields.push({ name: '✅ ¦ Agree', value: `0`, inline: true });
        fields.push({ name: '❌ ¦ Disagree', value: `0`, inline: true });
        embed.addFields(fields);

        // Create the buttons
        const agreeButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('agree')
            .setLabel('✅ Agree')
            .setStyle('Success');

        const disagreeButton = new ButtonBuilder()
            .setCustomId('disagree')
            .setLabel('❌ Disagree')
            .setStyle('Danger');

        // Create the action row
        const actionRow = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(agreeButton, disagreeButton);

        // Send the Embed message with the buttons
        const message = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [actionRow], fetchReply: true });

        // Create a thread
        const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.fetch(interaction.channelId);
        const startMessage = await channel.messages.fetch(message.id);
        const thread = await channel.threads.create({
            name: suggestion,
            autoArchiveDuration: 600,
            startMessage: startMessage,
        });

        // Handle the button click events
        const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ time: 600000 });

        collector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {
            const emoji = interaction.customId;

            // Get the current values of the Agree and Disagree fields
            const agreeField = embed.fields.find(field => field.name === '✅ ¦ Agree');
            const disagreeField = embed.fields.find(field => field.name === '❌ ¦ Disagree');

            // Update the value of the Agree or Disagree field based on which button was clicked
            if (emoji === 'agree') {
                agreeField.value = (parseInt(agreeField.value) + 1).toString();
            } else if (emoji === 'disagree') {
                disagreeField.value = (parseInt(disagreeField.value) + 1).toString();
            }

            // Update the message with the updated Embed message
            await interaction.update({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true });

            // Send an ephemeral message to indicate that the button click was successful
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'Your answer was submitted successfully!', ephemeral: true });
        });

        collector.on('end', async () => {
            // Lock the thread when the collector times out
            await thread.setLocked(true);
        });
    },
};
```

When I send the command `/suggest` it sends an Embed and creates a thread, but when I click the button `Agree` or `Disagree` the bot crashes and it sends this:

```
C:\Users\---\---\---\Commands\Public\suggest.js:61
            const agreeField = embed.fields.find(field => field.name === '✅ ¦ Agree');
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
    at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (C:\---\---\---\Commands\Public\suggest.js:61:45)
...
```

It meant to add +1 here when clicking `Agree` or `Disagree` button:

```
Suggestion
*Suggest name*
✅ ¦ Agree
0     //<------------ Add +1 Here when clicking `Agree` button.
❌ ¦ Disagree
0     //<------------ Add +1 Here when clicking `Disagree` button.
```

I also tried to make the buttons always active after restarting the bot using `interactionCreate.js` (But I think that it interacted with the rest of the code.). And, because, I'm too unclear feel free to ask me anything. Any answer is accepted! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `embed.fields` property. It should be `embed.data.fields`:

```js
const agreeField = embed.data.fields.find(
  (field) => field.name === '✅ ¦ Agree',
);
const disagreeField = embed.data.fields.find(
  (field) => field.name === '❌ ¦ Disagree',
);
```

Another thing that probably won't work is `autoArchiveDuration`, it should be one of `60`, `1440`, `4320`, or `10080`. Or you could import the `ThreadAutoArchiveDuration` and use `ThreadAutoArchiveDuration.OneHour`, etc.